# Update method time in HangFire RecurringJob?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I just discovered that with **HangFire** you can have background jobs running in your .Net application but when I was testing its functionalities, I realized that the **time** in the method I added to a **1 minute RecurringJob** does not change even though the method was triggered multiple times:

[image: Console Application]

**Method:**

```
private static string GetTime()
{
      return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

**RecurringJob statement:**

```
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("time", () => Console.WriteLine("Hello Hangfire! " + GetTime()), "*/1 * * * *");
```

**My question:**

Is it possible to display time updates as **RecurringJob** calls the method above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the string you pass to console.writeline is being serilized and that's why it gets the time when it the anonymous method is added, bug or not? well i guess it depends on what you expect from it to do.  it is explained in the documentation [Hangfire Passing arguments](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-arguments.html)

try using a method like this instead

```
private static void HelloWorldTime()
{
   Console.Writeline( "hello world! : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() );
}

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("time", HelloWorldTime() , "*/1 * * * *");
```